# unable to connect to localhost:80 after installing nginx

Tags: linux, networking, http, iptables, nginx

I just installed nginx by doing `sudo yum install nginx` and I'm unable to connect to it on port 80.

I tried stopping iptables by doing `sudo service iptables start` and was still unable to connect.

I'm testing this out by doing `telnet localhost 80`. Here's the output I'm getting back:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

When I try `telnet localhost 22` it works as I'd expect it to:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you actually running it?

I'd do:

```
netstat -lnt | grep 80
```

and see if something is actually running. If you're root, you could do:

```
netstat -lntp | grep 80
```

And it would show you the PID as well.

If you just brought it down, I wouldn't guarantee it's configured to run on port 80 anyway. It may be configured for another port, for testing.

Comment: That did the trick! Apparently I didn't do "sudo nginx". idk...  on Ubuntu when I do "sudo apt-get install openssh-server" it's started automatically and the keys are auto-generated. Kinda figured nginx / yum would behave similarly. Guess not. Thanks!

Comment: Fedora/RHEL do _not_ activate services just because you install them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
http{
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen localhost;  # <-probably will fix your problem. 
    location / {
      root /data/www;
    }
    location /images/ {
      root /data;      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add in host file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```